# Sum parts of a column separated by 0

Tags: matlab, sum

Suppose that you have a matrix with:

```
0 0 0 .... 0
A 0 0 .... 0
B 0 0 .... 0
C 0 0 .... 0
0 0 0 .... 0
D 0 0 .... 0
E 0 0 .... 0
```

If I want to get a new array with the output:

```
[A+B+C   D+E]
```

how would you do it? Of course I can always do loops and check for 0 but I'd like to know if there is any other alternative.

Comment: should this calculation be done on the first column only? how about the other columns?

Comment: It should be done in every column but I was thinking in doing a loop for the number of columns since the number of columns is small in comparison the number of rows.

Comment: A B C ... are symbols or numbers?

Comment: Is the number of groups the same for all columns?

Comment: Hazem) Numbers. Luis) Not necessary

Comment: Can there be several consecutive zeros? What's the desired output then? Take a look at my answer to see what I mean

Comment: Yes. I should only sum those numbers that are consecutive non zero, and each sum should be an element of the new output in row format, like in my example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`cumsum`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) to generate a vector of grouping values, and then [`accumarray`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to do the sums:

```
x = [0; 1; 2; 4; 0; 7; 3];
result = accumarray(cumsum(x==0) + (x(1)~=0), x);
```

gives

```
result =
     7
    10
```

The `+ (x(1)~=0)` part is necessary if `x` **may not start with a zero**. This part ensures that for

```
x = [1; 2; 4; 0; 7; 3];
```

the result is the desired

```
result =
     7
    10
```

With the above approach, **each zero**  starts a new group. So, for

```
x = [0; 1; 2; 4; 0; 7; 3; 0; 0; 5; 0];
```

the result is

```
result =
     7
    10
     0
     5
     0
```

If you want **each run of one or more zeros** to start a new group: first collapse consecutive zeros in `x`,  then apply the above:

```
x = [0; 1; 2; 4; 0; 7; 3; 0; 0; 5; 0];
ind = [true; x(2:end)~=0 | x(1:end-1)~=0]; % index to remove a zero if preceded by zero
t = x(ind);
result = accumarray(cumsum(t==0) + (x(1)~=0), t);
```

gives

```
result =
     7
    10
     5
     0
```

Comment: It gives me the error: error: accumarray: dimension mismatch with your example as it is. I am using octave. Could it be because of it?

Comment: @Learningfrommasters Sorry, the `.'` shouldn't have been there. Can you check now?

Comment: Works! althought if the first value of the column is not a 0, then you get the error: "error: accumarray: indices must be positive integers"

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. I think it can be easily solved adding `1` if `x(1)` is not `0`; please see now